# Who am I in this cruel world?

Tags: riddle

Here is a poem that can explain who I am.

> yellow and red
>
> screaming
>
> but beautifully
>
> yet, some has plus one

```
Y2V5RGRUUkpXRXQyZGxVPQ==
```